# When I am updating master branch why it shows conflict?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have just started learning git. I created one test branch from `master` branch. Did some change on `test` branch. Somebody did some changes on the `master` on remote. I am on my `test` branch and I took `git pull` of `master` branch. It shows `merge conflict`. Why there is merge conflict ? I can't understand. I know why conflict happens but I am taking update of `master` branch and not even asking git to pull those changes on my current `test` branch, so why is there a conflict. Whats happening ? Can anyone, please explain. How can I independently update my `master` branch without affecting my `test` branch.
Any help, highly appreciated.

Comment: Go to your `master` branch and run `git pull` there.

Comment: Do you execute `git pull origin master` on your `test` branch ? It will try to merge `master` to `test` in that way.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are on 'test' branch and you are taking a pull from 'master' which will fetch all the changes to your 'test' branch. If you want to update 'master' then checkout master independently and work there.

The best practice is to take a pull from the remote branch then update your code and resolve conflicts if any then push code to your branch so when you raise a PR to master, there will be no issue.

You can use [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) which is very user friendly.

For git, check this out: http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

Answer (score 0):

To avoid conflict run these commands in repo folder: `git fetch`, `git pull`, `git merge master`, `git rebase master`

source: https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/avoid-80-of-merge-conflicts-with-git-rebase-b5d755a082a6